# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined but state has been stored

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to get a specific team data from the database and store it in a state. But when I map an array inside that data it returns an error. When I console log my state it returns the data below

```
createdAt: "2021-03-19T13:36:22.868Z"
gameEvent: "basketball"
players: Array(5)
0: {_id: "605ea59c5cdf492b48987107", name: "Jerry Ale", jerseyNumber: "12"}
1: {_id: "605ea59c5cdf492b48987108", name: "Judel Agur", jerseyNumber: "14"}
2: {_id: "605ea59c5cdf492b48987109", name: "qwe", jerseyNumber: "12"}
3: {_id: "605ea59c5cdf492b4898710a", name: "qwe", jerseyNumber: "12"}
4: {_id: "605ea59c5cdf492b4898710b", name: "qwe", jerseyNumber: "12"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
teamName: "Balilihan"
updatedAt: "2021-03-27T03:25:16.148Z"
__v: 0
_id: "6054a8d63fec5c24389624ac"
```

I have an useEffect to gather this;

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getTeam = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get('get-all-teams');

                setIsLoaded(true);
                if (isLoaded === true) {
                    setCurrentTeam(data.find((team) => team._id === row._id));
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        getTeam();
    }, [fetchContext, row, isLoaded]);
```

and I map the `players` array in a new variable because I want a controlled inputs for my form because I am updating the data. I am using Formik by the way

```
let playersOfTeam = currentTeam.players.map((player, index) => [
            {
                name: player.name,
                jerseyNumber: player.jerseyNumber,
            },
        ]);
```

But when I just get a specific value like the teamName it returns the teamName and when I console log currentTeam.players it returns what I expected to get. I am confused why I get this kind of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is undefined when the component is first mounted. This is because `useEffect` runs *after* render.

So adding a null check is the solution. Personally I prefer optional chaining. Simply change to:

```
let playersOfTeam = currentTeam?.players?.map((player, index) => [
            {
                name: player.name,
                jerseyNumber: player.jerseyNumber,
            },
        ]);
```

Comment: Best answer ever!!! But how can I map the values in the input fields?

Comment: Glad it helped. If it solved your problem please accept this as the answer:) What do you mean by input fields. You mean the jsx `<input>` tag?

Comment: Yes, here is the link of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888690/does-not-render-initialvalues-that-i-declare-in-formik-and-why-is-my-array-value

Comment: I don't have much idea about that sadly. never used formik